# How to execute a iframe using javascript on a php page at specific server time?

Tags: javascript, php, bash, iframe

So,

I do not know exact how to do this but here is the thing -

I have the following with me -

1 PHP page let's say wordpress

1 iframe code lets say the following -

Now, my concern is this -

How do i execute this IFRAME on this PHP Page at specific time intervals counted by server time.

So, i need this IFRAME to work from 12AM to 12PM server time, how do i do this.

Sorry i am not a big coder or something.

Comment: Let's says that the iframe target is a php page. On that php page you check servertime, if time ok you continue and show the page. Otherwise your choice.

Comment: doing it via javascript you would need to get the timezone of the server and work out the time from that, which is not as easy as the PHP answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Just to build on Marco Mura's answer, here is the code example:

Declaring full variables:

```
$time_now = date('H:i'); //24 hour date format with leading zeros
$range_start = date('H:i', strtotime('00:00')); //Midnight
$range_end = date('H:i', strtotime('12:00')); //Midday

if(($time_now >= $range_start) && ($time_end <= $range_end)){
    //Go to iframe.
}else{
    //Do nothing
}
```

Simplified:

```
$time_now = date('H:i'); //24 hour date format with leading zeros

if(($time_now >= date('H:i', strtotime('00:00'))) && ($time_end <= date('H:i', strtotime('12:00'))){
    //Go to iframe.
}else{
    //Do nothing
}
```

Cool

Comment: Good Example (+1), If needed he can stop the iframe from the page who is the container or from the iframe itself :)